# Structural Search and Replace WITHOUT Resharper

Tags: regex, replace, resharper

I don't have Resharper but after some research found that its search and replace functionality would easily solve the problem I am having. The problem is I have many lines in code that look like:

`ex.foo`

where foo varies and ex doesn't. I need to change them all to look like:

`function(ex,"foo")`

I could probably write some script for this specific case, but since I am going to be needing to do this type of replacement a lot in the future with different flavors, is there a good general purpose solution available outside of Resharper? The main problem is not recognizing the initial string, but saving foo so that I can use it in the replacement string. I'm not sure how to do that with, for instance, regex replacers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If notepad++ is an option for you, you could open all documents and "Replace in all opened documents" in one turn with this regex:

`ex\.([a-zA-Z_]+)`

Replace with

`function(ex,"\1")`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. The problem as I noted was I was unsure how to reference matched variables in the replace, but I see now you can use `\1`. And for the record I had to replace with `function\(ex,"\1"\)` since the parentheses had to be escaped.

Comment: That's odd, I tested it and it worked without escaping the parantheses. But anyway, great if it works for you.

Comment: Yep, when I tried it without escaping, the parentheses did not display in the replaced text. Chalk it up to different notepad++ version conventions I guess. Thanks again anywho.